# How could a typical partition scheme look like on a bootable thumbdrive with uefi and diskencryption?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, gpt, disk-encryption

I am now playing with uefi and read about some kind of basics, which seem to be:

- Create a partition table of type GPT
- Create an efi partition, type fat16
- in this partition create a structure like /EFI/BOOT
- put in the proper .efi-file ( either 32 or 64 bit ) into the boot-folder

This should allow to autoboot the computer, from what I have read, the structure above, will be enough, so that the efi-bios-subsystem knows where to look for the .efi file, which then gets executed.

I would like to do this for an usb-stick, which should be a bootable thumbdrive with an os installed, but with encryption.

So, I would ask for some hints/best practices/experience in how to set up
my partitions, if I would like to have a bootable thumbdrive, being capable of handling uefi-bios with an encrypted partition for the os.

THX in advance.